# Dynamically build quadtiles compatible with spherical Mercator (mathematics)

Tags: tiles, web-mercator

I have a spherical Mercator map in degrees coordinates (-180, -85, 180, 85) programmed.
I add points to it one-by-one, and on some condition (*ex, there are more than 25 points on map*), I split this map into 4 maps and move all points to those 4 maps.

Next, I have four maps:

- `(-180, -85, 0, 0)`
- `(0, 0, 180, 85)`
- `(-180, 0, 0, 85)`
- `(0, -85, 180, 0)`

I start to add points to those maps, and at some confition I need to split one of those maps into four pieces. But there is a problem: I can not just divide latitude by 2, as I want those maps be in conformance with quadtile system.

How can I find a mathematical expression to split custom `[lat1; lat3]` section into two pieces to be in conformance with spherical Mercator system?

As far as I understand, this will help me:

```
# REST: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#Python
lat2 = y2lat(lat2y(lat1) + (lat2y(lat3) - lat2y(lat1) / 2)
```

but maybe there is some more optimal formula?

Answer (score 1):

Web Mercator tiles are normally used to fill in a viewport with predefined tiles appropriate to a current zoom level. You seem to be thinking about tiling based on the amount of data added to a particular tile so I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish,

If you are interested in generating tiles properly aligned to the x/y/zoom tiling specification (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), you may want to look at this library that defines functions that will help you compute coordinates and bounding boxes for tiles, and find the tile identifier (x/y/zoom) for a particular latitude / longitude coordinate pair: https://github.com/mapbox/mercantile.

Answer (score 1):

**`f1`: Original method:**

```
from math import atan, degrees, exp, log, tan, radians, pi, sqrt

def f1(a1, a3):
        def y2lat(r):
            return degrees(2 * atan(exp(r)) - pi / 2.0)

        def lat2y(a):
            return log(tan(pi / 4 + radians(a) / 2))

        return y2lat(lat2y(a1) + (lat2y(a3) - lat2y(a1)) / 2)
```

---

**`f2`: Mathematically-optimized method** (2.2x times faster than `f1`):

```
def f2(a1, a3):
    return degrees(2 * atan(sqrt(tan(pi / 4 + radians(a1 / 2)) * tan(pi / 4 + radians(a3 / 2)))) - pi / 2)
```

---

**`f5`: Speed-optimized version of `f2`** (3.2 times faster than `f1`, 1.5x times faster than `f2`):

```
def f5(a1, a3):
    # This is speed-optimized version of math-optimized version:
    # a2 = degrees(2 * atan(sqrt(tan(pi / 4 + radians(a1 / 2)) * tan(pi / 4 + radians(a3 / 2)))) - pi / 2)
    # Original unoptimized version based on https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator#Python
    # a2 = y2lat(lat2y(a1) + (lat2y(a3) - lat2y(a1)) / 2)

    # SPEED COMPARISON on 200 million calculations:
    #
    # ORIGINAL    MATH-OPTIMIZED    MATH-AND-SPEED-OPTIMIZED
    #   318%          152%                  100%
    #

    # Thanks to Ivan `ivan_matan` Valerievich P. for math optimization!

    # Speed-Optimization: Using inline float numbers here gives 50% boost on CPython 3.10
   return 114.5915590261646457292954437434673309326171875 * atan(
            sqrt(tan(0.78539816339744827899949086713604629039764404296875 +
                     a1 * 0.00872664625997164773718584029893463593907654285430908203125) *
                 tan(0.78539816339744827899949086713604629039764404296875 +
                     a3 * 0.00872664625997164773718584029893463593907654285430908203125))
                ) - 90.0
```

---

**Warning:** due to binary floating-point mathematics error, there is a tiny difference between calculated results of `f1` and `f5` and it is `Δ = 0.0000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625°` in some cases, wich is less than `1 μm` in real world.